# I downloaded Streamlit but now my numpy.unique function has stopped working

Tags: python, numpy, streamlit

I recently wanted to try the `Streamlit` package. I tried it, but decided not to use it. Afterwards I wanted to run my code, but the `numpy.unique` function gives the following error:

```
TypeError: _unique_dispatcher() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'equal_nan'
```

Another error that pops up is:

```
Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\utils\nsview.py:485: UserWarning: legacy printing option can currently only be '1.13', '1.21', or `False`
  set_printoptions(**np_printoptions)
```

I tried uninstalling and updating `numpy`, but it did nothing. Also downloading `numpy 1.21` did nothing